# Getting Intent Extras from Activity before onCreate method

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there any way to get intent extras inside `attachBaseContext()` method?

The Activity i am using is inside the framework project. I need to set Activity's language with `attachBaseContext()` method like:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
   super.attachBaseContext(LanguageContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, "en"));
}
```

I am sending language code string to Activity with `intent.putExtra()`. When i try to get extras inside `attachBaseContext()`, it throws NullPointerException error. How can it be done? Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing that you need to call `getExtras` after you call  `super.attachBaseContext(newBase)`

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek Yes maybe i can get the extras but I will not call the `super.attachBaseContext(newBase)` with extra parameters :(

Comment: Instead of storing in Extras, you could store in shared preferences and get the data from there, in attachBaseContext method.

Comment: Getting shared preferences parameters are not allowed from framework project. (mode_world_readable option is no longer supported) @Fustigador

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - To the best of my knowledge, this is impossible.

This is because Android calls `attachBaseContext` as soon as it attaches the `Activity` as can be seen [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#6618). Later, the intent is set inside the `Activity` class.

An alternative solution would be to store the variables in your `Application` subclass or in an application scoped repository of some kind.

For example,

`@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    String someLanguage = ((MyApplication)newBase.getApplicationContext()).getAppLanguage();
    super.attachBaseContext(LanguageContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, someLanguage));
}`

You could easily adapt this to use a repository pattern with Dagger or even SharedPreferences.